# How to tell whether a fork of a repo has commits not found in upstream

Tags: github

I have about 20 different repos forked in my GitHub account. Most of these, I forked an upstream repo, created a branch, uploaded a patch, submitted a pull request, and got the PR merged into upstream. So my fork of that repo can be deleted.

How do I tell which of my forks is redundant with upstream and can be deleted? If my fork of some repo has 20 branches, I don't want to check *for each branch* whether there are any commits not in the upstream branch.

Comment: Uhh... are you trolling? I've created several forks of repos and pull requests from those forks, usually using the edit button on GitHub to just change a file or two. Now I have 20 repos in my account that are forks,  and I want to know which of those 20 I can delete without deleting the ones with unmerged pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to check for each branch whether there are any commits not in the upstream branch.

Yet you should (for branches unique to your fork that is): the easiest way it to check if each branch HEAD is contained by the upstream repo.

Clone just the upstream repo, and then for a fork:

```
git ls-remote --heads /url/of/a/fork
```

(Using [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote), you don't have to clone all your forks, only the upstream repo)

For each SHA1 representing a branch which is *not* a branch of the upstream repo, do from the cloned upstream repo:

```
git branch --contains <SHA1>
```

If each HEAD is accessible from the upstream repo, the fork is truly obsolete.

I ignore all branches named like the ones found in the upstream repo, because said upstream repo could have rebase/rewritten those branch, and you are not supposed to develop directly on a common branch anyway (a PR should be done from a dedicated PR branch which does not exist in upstream)

Comment: To be clear, are you saying I should manually clone all 20 upstream repos to separate directories, and then run these commands on each directory? Is there no way on github.com to tell whether a repo even *has* any branches unique to my fork?

Comment: @mgiuffrida Sorry I though you had multiple forks of the same upstream repo. I don't know of a fully remote solution (on GitHub side)